# New-WebServiceProxy error with message "could not load file or assembly"

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm getting the following error when using the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet:

> Could not load file or assembly 'file:///.dll'
>   or one of its  dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

The WSDL was perfectly valid. After many hours of debugging, I found out that this message happens because the C# code generated for the Web Service classes is invalid. I don't know exactly why, but it appears that this error will always occur when the following naming pattern is used for the Web Methods:

```
[WebMethod]
public void AnyMethodName(...) { ... }

[WebMethod]
public void AnyMethodNameAsync(...) { ... }
```

I'm not sure of what is really happening, but I can tell that *changing the name of the first method will work, as well as changing the order that the methods appear within the class* - that is, the first method **cannot** be placed just before the second method.

The exception is thrown inside the method **GenerateWebServiceProxyAssembly** when returning the value of **results.CompiledAssembly**, as you can see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/WebServiceProxy.cs).

Does anyone knows what is really happening? Is this a bug of this cmdlet? Are there any solutions other than renaming the methods or chaging it's order inside the class?

Comment: did you find a means around this?

Comment: Nope, I ended up just changing the declaration order for the methods, since the problem was occurring on my own assembly.